# how to retrieve values from SQL into text area via selecting drop down list populated from SQL using javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I am trying to populate a text area with data from a table by selecting a name field of the same table in a drop down list.
the code i have is as follows. The drop down list is currently being populated from the SQL and all queries are in place. I am mainly unsure of the javascript required.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<li><label for="frm_precan">Canned Response</label>
            <span class="input">                        
                    <select id="frm_precan" name="precan" onchange="updateText();">
                            <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                            <?php foreach($precan_list as $precan) : ?>
                            <option value="<?=$precan['id'];?>"><?=$precan['name'];?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>            
                    </select>
            </span>
        </li>
        </ul>   
        <textarea id="txtmessage" style="width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 1; font-family: courier;" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function updateText()
            {
            document.getElementById('txtmessage').value = '';
            }
        </script>
```

Currently I have the javascript linking to the on change function and it clears the text area. I am trying to populate the text area with the same table information, only different fields from that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery for this

in the head section of your html add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then your function is:

```
    function updateText(){
        var value = $("#frm_precan option:selected").text();//id of select
        $('#text_area').val(value);
        }
```

In your html

```
    <textarea id="text_area"></textarea>
```

Comment: This was helpful. thanks, however there is a major part missing, and i now realise i didnt make this clear at all. what i want to be able to do is. --- have an "on change" on drop list (containing the titles) --- this on change runs the javascript function --- that populates the text area with a "message" column of data in the same table as the corresponding title that is being selected in the drop list.

Comment: more like this but so it actually does something. I am unsure when it comes to javascript. var value = $("<?=$precan['message'];?> where <?=$precan['name'];?> = $(#frm_precan option:selected)").text();

Comment: If undertand correctly you have 3 columns in your DB. ID,NAME,MESSAGE. If you want to populate the textarea with the column MESSAGE where NAME=OPTION.SELECTED then you should probably change your sql query. So every time you select something ONCHANGE, you get what you want. Otherwise when the function is being executed you have to use jquery or ajax to get a response from the server with the value you want from your DB and place it in the textarea.